# Karmic remnants after advice

Tags: karma, rebirth, nirvana

If you gave someone good or bad advice or wrote a book that was stored in the Library of Congress and read for centuries then wouldnt you have a karmic remnant to bear?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kauva Aatma, for a good, a bad or neither good or bad. Something most are not aware, talking "I know" and do not.

To make it short, best is it to compair it with a pit-fall. As long as it is not removed, if one actually get's trapped, the action is full filled.

Now think of how many debts some accumulate, debts keeping them to come back again and again... think on how much remorse might follow, once finding out a better.

One question, bringing that to awarness was: [Pitfalls of answers: what are effects of answers having be received, yet knowing they where …](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23768/pitfalls-of-answers-what-are-effects-of-answers-having-be-received-yet-knowing). Nyom Chris gave some practical advices.

Here as a sample directly, indirectly on this matter for understanding:

> For instance, if a bhikkhu harboring this sort of general intention builds a trap but then changes his mind, he has to destroy the trap so thoroughly that it cannot be reassembled. Similarly, when a bhikkhu writes a passage describing the advantages of dying (see below) with the thought that anyone who reads it might decide to commit suicide, if he then changes his mind he has to destroy the writing so thoroughly that it cannot be pieced together. If, instead of writing the passage himself, he simply picks up a pre-existing written passage of this sort and then — with a similar intention — puts it in a place where it might be easily seen, he can avoid any penalty simply by returning the passage to the place where he found it.

On effects of approve and encouragement by speech (eg. signs, gesture, letter) see also:

[AN 4.83: Avannaraha Sutta - Dispraise](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/index_en.html#an4) and [6. Acelakavaggo AN03.157-163](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.164-183.sang_en.html).

And that is why if is said:

> "Those who point out wrong Dhamma as Dhamma, Bhikkhus, those Bhikkhus archive harm for many people, suffering for many people, for the sorrow and suffering of heavenly and human beings. Much demerits, those produce, for the disappearing of the true Dhamma. This for the thirty third.
>
> 131. "Those who point out Dhamma as wrong Dhamma, those archive harm for many people, suffering for many people, for the sorrow and suffering of heavenly and human beings. Much demerits, those produce, for the disappearing of the true Dhamma. This for the thirty forth.
>
> 132-139. "Those who point out wrong Vinaya as Vinaya[2]... Vinaya as wrong Vinaya... not declared by the Tathagāta as declared by the Tathagāta... declared by the Tathagāta as not declared by the Tathagāta... not practised by the Tathagāta as practised by the Tathagāta... practised by the Tathagāta as not practised by the Tathagāta... not made know by the Tathagāta as made know by the Tathagāta... made know by the Tathagāta as not made know by the Tathagāta, those archive harm for many people, suffering for many people, for the sorrow and suffering of heavenly and human beings. Much demerits, those produce, for the disappearing of the true Dhamma. This for the forty second.

And not just for one and now... long time for one to wander on having overestimate one self, not to speak on deliberately account.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Answer (score 0):

Karma is intention. So, it depends if the person bears in his/her heart the honest wish for the benefit or prejudice of the others. And Later, if he/she recollect and rejoice in the past deed and the repercuition, this generate karma as well.